# Fixing green coloration on clapboard siding

Tags: paint, siding

My wife and I are in the process of closing on a home and we're planning some initial renovations we want to make before we move in.

We noticed that there's a small area (maybe ten square feet) of the north side of the house that has some slight green coloration on the siding, which is painted clapboard. It might be mildew or algae.

Who would be the best contractor to remedy this? Does it need to be sanded down and repainted, or is it possible to "clean" clapboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only mildew or algae, you can probably just clean it off pretty easily with [oxygen bleach](https://www.google.com/search?q=oxygen%20bleach&tbm=shop) (sodium percarbonate). Mix it up with water to the concentration specified by the manufacturer, spray it on the clapboard, wait about 15 minutes, then scrub it with a cleaning brush.

I'd test this on a small, non-conspicuous area first to make sure it doesn't effect the color - oxygen bleach won't bleach the pigments themselves, but it may remove oxidation or sun damage on the top of the paint. It certainly shouldn't be as noticeable as sanding and repainting the area though.